# Am I allowed to ask for and store a user's itunesconnect password?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, authentication, app-store-connect, osx-mountain-lion

I am building an Apple developer analytics app, which displays info stored in itunesconnect Daily Sales Reports. Thus I would like to automatically download these Daily Sales Reports (which I achieved by using this [script](http://raybbo.com/blog/2011/08/28/bash-script-app-store-auto-ingest-tool/)). This app will be released on the Mac App Store and is sandboxed.

Am I allowed to ask for and store a user's itunesconnect password?

If so, what is the correct way to do it?

EDIT:
Thank you James and Michael, Keychain Services is definitely the way to go.

I do have one follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503708/whats-the-correct-way-to-prompt-a-user-for-their-password).

Comment: I can't think of a reason why you wouldn't be allowed. I expect the solution would make use of Keychain Access.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this for certain but if you do, make certain you use [Keychain Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html), which is the best (if not Apple's only preferred) way to store passwords securely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, thank you James and Michael, and the correct way to store it is with Keychain Services. I used an objective-c wrapper that you can find [here](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain).

Answer (score -1):

Disregard my earlier comment, I misunderstood your question (I thought you were trying to access a database). If the user gives you the information willingly, there is not problem; the issues would arise if you tried to trick the users into giving you the information. As for the correct way to do this, you could just ask them to put in their password, giving them the ways you would use them. There would, however, possibly be legal issues down the road if you use the passwords in a different way then you tell the user.

Comment: I'll not downvote you as I can see you are quite a new user, however I believe you are wrong. Firstly, legally, Apple aren't even a part of this. The only legal problems with gathering passwords is adhering to the Data Protection Act and not misusing the stored passwords. Also, this app wouldn't require the developer to actually store the passwords on a server / anywhere they can actually read them

Comment: Secondly, I haven't actually tried, but I expect this app WILL require a password to gather specific sales data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was under the impression that Itunesconnect, and therefore all the user data, including passwords, was controlled by Apple.

Comment: Think of it like this: When you use iTunesConnect, you login, yes. With this app, you will still login, once, then your information will be stored by the app and used again later automatically. The app just acts as an interface between you and your normal use of iTunesConnect.

Comment: Oh, ok, I guess I didn't understand the question correctly. I was under the impression that he was trying to access the passwords from a database, not from the users themselves.