# Whats the Correct Way to Prompt a User for their Password?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, security, osx-mountain-lion, keychain

This is a follow up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12450866/am-i-allowed-to-ask-for-and-store-a-users-itunesconnect-password).

If I'm going to store a user's username and password with Keychain Services, should I simply create my own prompt view with an NSSecureTextField for the password, and then once the user enters their info pass it to a Keychain Services API ([I found this one](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain))?

I'm concerned Apple won't like me interacting with a users sensitive data directly like that.

Comment: Take a look at [SSKeychain](https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the only way use a user's password for Apple's Autoingest tool is to handle the password directly in code. I make sure to not hold onto it longer than I need it, and of course I store it with Keychain Services in order to keep it secure.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like the appropriate thing to do. The following function calls will do the stuff you need.

```
SecKeychainAddGenericPassword();
SecKeychainFindGenericPassword();
SecKeychainItemModifyAttributesAndData();
SecKeychainItemCopyContent();
SecKeychainItemFreeContent();
SecKeychainItemDelete();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was asking about how to get the password from the user, not how to store it securely.